# Project Euler 31: Coin Sums - Recursive Solution Runs Infinitely

Tags: python, recursion

Project Euler 31 (how many ways can 200p be made with 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, 100p, and 200p).

I am attempting this with very beginner recursive code.  This keeps appearing that it would make sense, but it ends up finding more and more ways to subtract 1p from 1p.  I've tried tracing the branches, and all sorts of debug methods, but can't quite make sense as to why this method doesn't give a straightforward answer:

```
startval = 200
denoms = [200, 100, 50, 20 , 10, 5, 2, 1]
runningtot = 0

def recr(currval):
    global runningtot
    if currval == 0:
        runningtot += 1
        return None
    for denom in denoms:
        if denom <= currval:
            a = recr(currval-denom)
    return None

a = recr(startval)

print(runningtot)
```

I understand the variable a is superfluous.  Just wanted to give the function something to return into such that the recursive stack call could find an exit.

Thank you in advance, and apologies for my novice coding.

Comment: Seems like the problem may have an analytical solution (not brute force) using some combinatorics methods.

Comment: @SergeyTsaplin - I was thinking that as well.  I am clueless about combinatorics, so trying some other methods first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is not that your loop is infinite. It's just very inefficient, and it's also not answering the actual question (that's part of it being very inefficient).

For example, to simplify, let's take this example:

```
startval = 5
denoms = [5,2,1]
```

How many ways are there to make up 5?

1. 5
2. 2 + 2 + 1
3. 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
4. 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

However, your code will give 9 on these values. Think why. Hint: you are counting the "same" things multiple times.

So basically your code is both (a) inefficient by itself, (b) has a bug in the design which causes it to be inefficient even more

For (a) - check out dynamic programming / memoization
For (b) - That's the "hint" I gave you.

*Tip - when you are having difficulties with getting results from your code, start by inputing small values. See that the results for these values make sense.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To implement a recursive solution you should think of it as an incremental step over a simpler problem of the same nature.   In this case the ways to get 200p with coins of 1p, 2p, ... can be defined as the sum of ways to get it using the first coin zero, 1, 2, 3, ... times up to using only the first coin value.

In other words, the total of

```
ways to get 200p with [2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, ...] (i.e using no 1p coins)
ways to get 199p with [2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, ...] (i.e using one 1p coin)
ways to get 198p with [2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, ...] (i.e using two 1p coins)
...
ways to get 100p with [2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, ...] (i.e using one hundred 1p coins)
...
ways to get 2p   with [2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, ...] (i.e using 198 x 1p coins)
ways to get 1p   with [2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, ...] (i.e using 199 x 1p coins)
one way to get 200p using only 1p coins
```

To get the count for each sub target of *"200p minus 1p coins used"* you simply call your function recursively with the rest of the coins.

When you get to a point where there's only one type of coin, count 1 solution if the target is a multiple of the coin value, otherwise the target can't be obtained and you would count zero.

Translated into Python code, this would be a very simple function:

```
def coinCounts(target,value,*rest):
    if not rest: return 0 if target % value else 1    # Only one coin value
    return sum( coinCounts(target-used,*rest)         # Total of ways using
                for used in range(0,target+1,value) ) # varying numbers of the first coin value


answer = coinCounts(200,*[1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200])
print(answer) # 73682
```

If you want to see what the solutions are, you can use the same approach but return the coin usage instead of only counting ways:

```
def coinsUsed (target,value,*rest):
    if target % value == 0 :
        yield [f"{target//value} x {value}p"]*(target>0)
    if not rest: return
    for total in range(0,target,value):
        for others in coinsUsed(target-total,*rest):
            yield next(coinsUsed(total,value))+others

for solution in coinsUsed(200,*[1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200]):
    print(*solution,sep=" + ")   

200 x 1p
100 x 2p
40 x 5p
20 x 10p
10 x 20p
4 x 50p
2 x 100p
1 x 200p
2 x 50p + 1 x 100p
5 x 20p + 2 x 50p
5 x 20p + 1 x 100p
1 x 10p + 2 x 20p + 3 x 50p
1 x 10p + 2 x 20p + 1 x 50p + 1 x 100p
1 x 10p + 7 x 20p + 1 x 50p
2 x 10p + 9 x 20p
... and thousands more ...

solutionCount = sum(1 for _ in coinsUsed(200,*[1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200]))
print(solutionCount) # 73682
```